# What is "Call By Name"?

Tags: scala, scheme, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I'm working on a homework assignment where we are asked to implement an evaluation strategy called "call by name" in a certain language that we developed (using Scheme).

We were given an [example in Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/138), but I don't understand how "call by name" works and how it is different to "call by need"?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Call-by-need is a memoized  version of call-by-name (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy)).

In call-by-name, the argument is evaluated *every time it is used*, whereas in call-by-need, it is evaluated the first time it is used, and the value recorded so that subsequently it need not be re-evaluated.

Comment: i already have implemented call by need, and when i was doing it the first implementation was without caching, i don't make sense to me that the professor asks me to do something that i already have done, because that i want to understand the truly difference between call by need and call by name

Comment: i confirmed with the professor, that is call by name, i was confused because we already write that code and now he is asking us again for that

Comment: "is evaluated the first time it is used, and the value recorded so that subsequently it need not be re-evaluated" seems more like a description of memoization than call-by-name.

Answer (score 19):

Call by name is a a parameter passing scheme where the parameter is evaluated when it is used, not when the function is called. Here's an example in pseudo-C:

```
int i;
char array[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };

i = 0;
f(a[i]);

int f(int j)
{
    int k = j;    // k = 0
    i = 2;        // modify global i
    k = j;        // The argument expression (a[i]) is re-evaluated, giving 2.
}
```

The argument expression is lazily evaluated when accessed using the current values of the argument expression.

Comment: Lazy evaluation is evaluate at most once, call-by-name is evaluate zero, one or more times.

Comment: I don't know about Scheme, but in Scala (which has no lazy parameters), that distinction is entirely accurate.

Comment: is this function supposed to print(k) in the end? What's the return value ?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the above answers:

Work through the [SICP section on Streams](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5). It gives a good explanation of both call-by-name and call-by-need. It also shows how to implement those in Scheme. BTW, if you are looking for a quick solution here is a basic call-by-need implemented in Scheme:

```
 ;; Returns a promise to execute a computation. (implements call-by-name)
 ;; Caches the result (memoization) of the computation on its first evaluation
 ;; and returns that value on subsequent calls. (implements call-by-need)
 (define-syntax delay
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ (expr ...))
       (let ((proc (lambda () (expr ...)))
             (already-evaluated #f)
             (result null))
         (lambda ()
           (if (not already-evaluated)
               (begin
                 (display "computing ...") (newline)
                 (set! result (proc))
                 (set! already-evaluated #t)))
           result)))))

 ;; Forces the evaluation of a delayed computation created by 'delay'.
 (define (my-force proc) (proc))
```

A sample run:

```
> (define lazy (delay (+ 3 4)))
> (force lazy) 
computing ... ;; Computes 3 + 4 and memoizes the result.
7
> (my-force lazy) 
7 ;; Returns the memoized value.
```

Comment: `delay` and `force` are r5rs, though? actually, at least as old as r3rs.

Comment: @sgm yes, they are part of the standard. I just wanted to show how they can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

***Call-by-name*** strategy does not evaluate arguments of the function until using them.

Example of *call-by-name* steps in Scala:

```
def square(a: Int) = a * a

// (b: => Int, c: => Int means that Scala will evaluate b and c with call-by-name startegy
def sumSquare(b: => Int, c: => Int ): Int = square(b) + square(c)

sumSquare(2, 3+3)
square(2) + square(3+3)
2 * 2 + square(3+3)
4 + square(3+3)
4 + (3+3) * (3+3) // duplicate evaluation
4 + 9 * (3+3)
4 + 9 * 9
85
```

*Call-by-name* can produce duplicates of evaluations. Also, the side effects of this strategy are less predictable. That's why the default Scala strategy is *call-by-value.*

You can read about the *call-by-name* strategy and the difference between *call-by-value* strategy here:
https://www.scaler.com/topics/call-by-name/

***Call-by-need*** strategy, also known as a lazy evaluation strategy, evaluates an expression the first time it called, and uses a dictionary to keep the result of the evaluation for a specific expression.

More about lazy evaluation (*call-by-need*) here:
https://medium.com/background-thread/what-is-lazy-evaluation-programming-word-of-the-day-8a6f4410053f