# Functions and function literals in scala

Tags: scala, function, literals, function-literal

I am new to Scala. Please tell the difference between

```
    def fun( t: Int => Int):Unit = {
```

and

```
    def fun(t: =>Int):Unit {
```

and

```
    def fun(t:=>Int):Unit { (without space b/w ":" and "=>"))
```

Answer (score 4):

`def fun( t: Int => Int):Unit` is a method that takes a single argument, `t`. Its type, `Int => Int`, is a function that takes an `Int`, and returns an `Int`. However, the return type of `fun` is `Unit`.

`def fun(t: =>Int):Unit` is a method that accepts a [call by name](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/26/call-by-name.html) argument `t`. Again, this method's return type is `Unit`.

See [What is "Call By Name"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962987/what-is-call-by-name) too.

There's no difference between the second and third methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but is "def fun( t: Int => Int):Unit" also call by name?

Comment: No since `=>` prefixes a call by name argument. It does not in the case you mentioned.

Comment: I am sorry but can you elaborate. When I ran the code with def fun( t: Int => Int):Unit and passed a function in fun, that function was called only when I used the variable "t". So, isnt it call by name?

Comment: Well, you **applied** an `Int` to `Int => Int` in order to call that function. However, in the call by name example, i.e. `def fun(t: => Int)`, `t` becomes evaluated only when it's called and every time it's called. Example: `def fun(t: => Int): Int = t + t`, and calling it:
 `fun( {println("calling fun"); 42} )` to observe that `calling fun` will print out twice, and `84` will be returned.